# $C^0$ is a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, continuity, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set. Let $f\in C^0(\bar\Omega)$. I have to prove that $\|f\|_{\infty}=\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$. One implication is trivial. Let's consider the other one.

$$
\|f\|_{\infty}=\min\{K>0:|f(x)|\le  K\,\,\,\, \forall x \in\bar\Omega\}\\
\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}=\inf\{K>0:|f(x)|\le K\,\,\,\,\,\mathrm{a.e. }x \in\Omega\}.
$$

Let $K>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le K$ for every $x\in\Omega\setminus N$, where $|N|=0$. 
Since $f$ is continuous we have that $|f(x)|\le K$ for every $x\in\overline{\Omega\setminus N}$ **(why?)**.

Then, I can conclude showing that $\bar\Omega\subseteq\overline{\Omega\setminus N}$.

Comment: If you had $\lvert f(x_0)\rvert > K$, there'd be an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ ...

Comment: I ask you another question. The following results hold.

 - **Theorem** Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Then $C^0_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $(L^p(\Omega),\|\cdot\|_p)$, if $1\le p<\infty$.
 - **Theorem** Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Then $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $(L^p(\Omega),\|\cdot\|_p)$, if $1\le p<\infty$.

Why these result do not hold for $p=\infty$? Maybe because $L^{\infty}$ is not separable?

Comment: What does $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{L^\infty}$-convergence mean for continuous functions? Hence what is a necessary condition for all $L^\infty$ functions in the closure of $C(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$? Extra points: what further necessary conditions are there for functions in the closure of $C_c(\Omega)$?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_{L^{\infty}}$-convergence for continuos functions is the uniform convergence. If, by contradiction, $\overline{ C^0_c(\Omega)}=L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then, recalling that $C^0_c(\Omega)$ is separable and closed we would have that $L^\infty$ is separable. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, got no notification for your response, or I missed it. Anyway, yes, uniform convergence. The next I meant in a different way than you read it, I meant what property must all functions in the closure of $C(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ (and hence a fortiori all functions in the closure of $C_c(\Omega)$) have? Your argument: $C_c(\Omega)$ is not closed in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. But the argument that the closure of a separable subspace is still separable is correct. So from the separability of $C_c(\Omega)$ and the non-separability of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ it indeed follows that $C_c(\Omega)$ is

Comment: not dense in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. However, is the separability of $C_c(\Omega)$ (with respect to the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$-norm) really obvious? [Depends on what you have to work with.]

Comment: You are right! Indeed is a nontrivial proof. But I can base my reasoning on this one because our professor proved it in class. Thank you very much! You are always very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Lemma.** If $g\colon\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$ is continuous and $g(x)\leqslant 0$ for each $x\in A$, then $g(x)\leqslant 0$ for each $x\in \overline A$.

We use this with $g(x):=|f(x)|-K$ and $A:=\Omega\setminus N$.

To show the lemma, take $x$ in the closure of $A$ and $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ a sequence of elements of $A$ converging to $x$. Then $g(x_n)\leqslant 0$ for each $n$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}g(x_n)=g(x)$ by continuity of $g$.